# How to mock a variable in ES6 Module with jest such that the actual function runs with mocked value

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

Here is a sample code where I want to test the function buttonReducer.
But the case names in the reducer functions are generated in another function.
So, when I want to test my reducer alone, I want to override the RESET_TYPE, FETCH_TYPE, and SHOW_TYPE so that I am able to test all the scenarios.

```
//main reducer.js
import {getActionTypeName} from './functions';

export const RESET_TYPE = getActionTypeName('RESET');
export const FETCH_TYPE = getActionTypeName('RESET');
export const SHOW_TYPE = getActionTypeName('RESET');

const initialState = {
  name: 'John'
};

export const buttonReducer = (state = {...initialState}, action){
  switch(action.type){
    case RESET_TYPE: {
      const newState = {"some random change", ...initialState};
      return newState;
    }
    case FETCH_TYPE: {
      const newState = {"some random change", ...initialState};
      return newState;
    }
    case SHOW_TYPE: {
      const newState = {"some random change", ...initialState};
      return newState;
    }
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}
```

Here are few things that I tried:

1.

```
jest.mock('./functions', ()=> {
    return {
        getActionTypeName: ()=>('return whatever I want')
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work.

2. I am fully aware of running the entire app using redux-mock-store. But what I am specifically looking for, is to just override existing variables so that I can do scenario tests on a function

So essentially, I want to run the reducer by changing the values of the variables and not merely mock them just for the test case.

Comment: Why not pass the action with different action types? So you can test each code branch of the reducer function

Comment: @slideshowp2, I do, but the case identifiers receive undefined as they are variables. They need to be resolved during runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Since the action types `RESET_TYPE`, `FETCH_TYPE`, and `SHOW_TYPE` are defined and calculated in module scope at runtime, in order to eliminate the caching effect of the module `import`, [jest.resetModules()](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestresetmodules) method is required. Before executing the test case, we need to call it. So that we can get a fresh module with fresh module variables. This prevents test cases from influencing each other.

Now, we can use [jest.doMock(moduleName, factory, options)](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestdomockmodulename-factory-options) and [mockFn.mockReturnValueOnce(value)](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockreturnvalueoncevalue) methods to mock `./functions` module and `getActionTypeName` function with different returned value for each test case.

E.g.

`reducer.js`:

```js
import { getActionTypeName } from './functions';

export const RESET_TYPE = getActionTypeName('RESET');
export const FETCH_TYPE = getActionTypeName('RESET');
export const SHOW_TYPE = getActionTypeName('RESET');

const initialState = {
  name: 'John',
};

export const buttonReducer = (state = { ...initialState }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case RESET_TYPE: {
      const newState = { a: 'a', ...initialState };
      return newState;
    }
    case FETCH_TYPE: {
      const newState = { b: 'b', ...initialState };
      return newState;
    }
    case SHOW_TYPE: {
      const newState = { c: 'c', ...initialState };
      return newState;
    }
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
};
```

`functions.js`:

```js
export function getActionTypeName() {
  console.log('real implementation');
}
```

`reducer.test.js`:

```js
describe('68179950', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
  });
  it('should return dynamic RESET_TYPE', () => {
    jest.doMock('./functions', () => ({
      getActionTypeName: jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce('RUNTIME_RESET_TYPE'),
    }));
    const { buttonReducer } = require('./reducer');
    const actual = buttonReducer({}, { type: 'RUNTIME_RESET_TYPE' });
    expect(actual).toEqual({ name: 'John', a: 'a' });
  });

  it('should return dynamic FETCH_TYPE', () => {
    jest.doMock('./functions', () => ({
      getActionTypeName: jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce('RUNTIME_RESET_TYPE').mockReturnValueOnce('RUNTIME_FETCH_TYPE'),
    }));
    const { buttonReducer } = require('./reducer');
    const actual = buttonReducer({}, { type: 'RUNTIME_FETCH_TYPE' });
    expect(actual).toEqual({ name: 'John', b: 'b' });
  });

  it('should return dynamic SHOW_TYPE', () => {
    jest.doMock('./functions', () => ({
      getActionTypeName: jest
        .fn()
        .mockReturnValueOnce('RUNTIME_RESET_TYPE')
        .mockReturnValueOnce('RUNTIME_FETCH_TYPE')
        .mockReturnValueOnce('RUNTIME_SHOW_TYPE'),
    }));
    const { buttonReducer } = require('./reducer');
    const actual = buttonReducer({}, { type: 'RUNTIME_SHOW_TYPE' });
    expect(actual).toEqual({ name: 'John', c: 'c' });
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  examples/68179950/reducer.test.js (18.013 s)
  68179950
    ✓ should return dynamic RESET_TYPE (12582 ms)
    ✓ should return dynamic FETCH_TYPE (1 ms)
    ✓ should return dynamic SHOW_TYPE (7 ms)

------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File        | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files   |   93.33 |       60 |     100 |   92.86 |                   
 reducer.js |   93.33 |       60 |     100 |   92.86 | 26                
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        22.095 s
```

Comment: Wow! Looks promising. Will surely try this out.

Answer (score 1):

You can have your mock return a jest fn that you can later change the return value for. That way you don't have to do a new mock each time.

```
const getActionTypeName = jest.fn(() => {});

jest.mock('./pathToModule', () => {
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    getActionTypeName: () => getActionTypeName(),
  }
})

describe('functionBeingTested', () => {
  it('should do something', () => {
    getActionTypeName.mockReturnValue('RUNTIME_RESET_TYPE');
    // test code...
    // assertions...
  });
});
```